# Can I have two actions in one IconButton?

Tags: flutter, dart, iconbutton

I want the speech to text function to start when one microphone icon is pressed and the noise meter function to start at the same time.

Currently, the icon for speech to text and the icon for noise meter are separated.
Is there any way to combine these into one icon?

- noise_meter

```dart
IconButton(
    onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
            _isRecording = !_isRecording;

            if (_isRecording) {
                NoiseMeterHelper().start(
                    onData: onData,
                    onError: onError,
                );
            } else {
                NoiseMeterHelper().stop();
            }
        });
    },
    icon: _isRecording ? Icon(Icons.mic) : Icon(Icons.mic),
),
```

- speech_to_text

```dart
IconButton(
    onPressed: recognizing ? stopRecording : streamingRecognize,
    icon: recognizing
        ? Icon(Icons.mic, color: Colors.red, size: 30)
        : Icon(Icons.mic, color: Colors.blue,size: 30)
),
```

Comment: Do you want both icons on the same button?

Comment: yes. When I press one button, the speech to text and noise meter should run at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run any number of functions in one `onPressed` function.

Also, you don't have to use `setState()` to run functions. `setState` is used to update class variables and rebuild the UI with those changes.

if you are displaying `_isRecording` or using it to update any UI, wrap it in a `setState`. If not, no need to use `setState`. Also, note that incorrect use of `setState` will lead to multiple unnecessary UI rebuilds.

Try this,

```dart
IconButton(
    onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
            _isRecording = !_isRecording;
        });

        if (_isRecording) {
            NoiseMeterHelper().start(
                onData: onData,
                onError: onError,
            );
        } else {
            NoiseMeterHelper().stop();
        }
        recognizing ? stopRecording() : streamingRecognize();
    },
    icon: _isRecording ? Icon(Icons.mic) : Icon(Icons.mic),
),
```